# How to turn this code in to a sql delete function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I was wondering how I could go about turning this add entry link in to a delete entry link? Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (CAN_EDIT){
    echo '<i>'.$announcements[$x]['page_edit']='<a href="index.php?id='.$announcements[$x]['page_id'].'&act=edit">edit entry</a></i><br />';
if ($announcements[$x]['page_edit']>0){}
                        }
```

I understand about using

```
mysql_query DELETE FROM (table name) WHERE (item name)
```

I am just not sure how to implement it and make it a link.

Comment: `id='.$announcements[$x]['page_id'].'` so `mysql_query delete from (table) WHERE id = $_GET['id']`

Comment: Shouldn't `'<i>'.$announcements[$x]['page_edit']='<a...'` be `'<i>'.$announcements[$x]['page_edit'].'<a...'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really up to how your application handles the requests. The edit link code you posted shows that two parameters are being passed to the PHP: `id` and `act`. Both will be available within `$_GET` in PHP when the link is clicked.

From that, we can infer that your code is checking `$_GET['act']` to decide what to do. If it is equal to `'edit'`, you'll probably fetch some data from the DB (for records where `id` equals `$_GET['id']`), then render an edit form.

Using that same logic, you should create a link with `id=N&act=delete` (where `N` is an actual ID). Then in PHP you check if the value of `$_GET['act']` is `'delete'`, then run the SQL query to delete the row with the ID passed.

Also, make sure to do a little research on SQL injection -- you should not use `$_GET` or `$_POST` values directly in the query, as that would make your app vulnerable to injection. Take a look at the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function on the PHP manual.

Comment: Do not underestimate the importance of the last paragraph in this answer, especially when working with publicly readable `$_GET` parameters! Keeping that in mind, read JKirchartz' comment on your question and immediately forget about it. Very bad advice that will get you in trouble sooner or later. Always clean user input before using it in queries.

Comment: +1 @Remco. The solution works great until you run across the id ";DROP  ALL TABLES", at which point you've got problems.

Comment: There will only be a handful of people who will have access to be able to delete entries. And they wont be able to do it unless they are logged in to the system.